# Can't create rounded border with component "ImageBackground"

Tags: react-native, user-interface, jsx, mobile-development

I need to create component like

[image: component]

Here is part of my code

```
<ImageBackground source={{uri}} style={{width: 234, height: 165, marginTop: 10, borderRadius: 10}}>
  <Text style={{margin: 10, fontSize: 24, fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'white'}}>
      Test
  </Text>
  <Text style={{marginLeft: 7, marginTop: 80, color: 'white'}}>
    <Icons name="distance" size={25} style={{color: 'white'}}></Icons>
    <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>
      2 KM
    </Text>
    <Text>   </Text>
    <Icons name="star" size={25} style={{color: 'white'}}></Icons>
    <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>
      4.9
    </Text>
  </Text>
</ImageBackground>
```

Prop style `borderRadius` doesn't works with component `ImageBackground`.
I tried to use various wrappers, but didn't get any results, also I tried to use `Image` component, but this component cannot contain other components (`Text` for ex.)

Comment: While images show what is needed, they can be removed by time and your question loses part of information possibly useful for future readers. The code should be placed as text (formatted as code), so it creates [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Images such as first are fine, describing what you need, visually, but never post code/errors as image. You (or other user) should replace the code snip by textual form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this way

```
<ImageBackground
  style={{height: 100, width: 100}}
  imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 6}} < -- like this -->
  source={{ uri: 'www.imageislocatedhere.com }}
>
```